# How do I use a custom comparator function with BTreeSet?

Tags: rust

In C++, it is possible to customize the code [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) uses to sort its arguments.  By default it uses [`std::less`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less), but that can be changed with the [`Compare`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare) template parameter.

Rust's [`BTreeSet`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeSet.html) uses the [`Ord`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Ord.html) trait to sort the type.  I don't know of a way to override this behavior -- it's built into the type constraint of the type stored by the container.

However, it often makes sense to build a list of items that are sorted by some locally-useful metric that nevertheless is not the best way to *always* compare the items by.  Or, suppose I would like to sort items of a `use`d type; in this case, it's impossible to implement `Ord` myself for the type, even if I want to.

The workaround is of course to build a plain old `Vec` of the items and `sort` it afterward.  But in my opinion, this is not as clean as automatically ordering them on insertion.

Is there a way to use alternative comparators with Rust's container types?

Comment: A nicer (or at least different) workaround is to define a newtype around the element type and implement your desired `Ord` instance on that.

Comment: True, although then you have your code littered with `map`s to and from the custom type (which of course compile away to nothing).  Still, decent idea.  I wonder if it would be possible to create a wrapper type for that pattern, where you pass the custom type constructor the source type and the comparator.

Comment: @thirtythreeforty, what do you mean by an O(log n) operation becoming O(n log n)? (I can't see an operation that is O(log n) other than, say, a single tree operation, but nothing that involves building a list will be O(log n).)

Comment: @huon oh, that's true. Duh.  Well that makes me feel a little better about the way I'm doing it now.

Comment: This may be far too late to be of any use to you @GeorgeHilliard, but for future readers of this question it may be helpful to know that my (recently published) [copse](https://crates.io/crates/copse) crate provides an alternative `BTreeSet` that can be instantiated with a custom/runtime-defined comparator.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Custom comparators currently do not exist in the Rust standard collections. The idiomatic way to solve the issue is to define a [*newtype*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#using-the-newtype-pattern-for-type-safety-and-abstraction):

```
struct Wrapper(Wrapped);
```

You can then define a custom [`Ord`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Ord.html) implementation for `Wrapper` with exactly the semantics you want.

Furthermore, since you have a newtype, you can also easily implement other traits to facilitate conversion:

- [`convert::From`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html) can be implemented, giving you [`convert::Into`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html) for free
- [`ops::Deref<Target = Wrapped>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) can be implemented, reducing the need for mapping due to auto-deref

Note that accessing the wrapped entity is syntactically lightweight as it's just two characters: `.0`.

Comment: Great!  Now that you mention the various traits, this might even end up being cleaner from a type perspective than C++'s approach.