# How do I sort data according to diferent criteria, without having to copy it?

Tags: rust

I have a `Vec<MyType>`. For my algorithm, I need `MyType` elements sorted according to different criteria. One is the insertion order, for which `Vec<MyType>` is used directly: I just index the element in the vector.

I also need to have `MyType` elements ordered by two other criteria.

In C++, I would simply create a `std::set<size_t>`, insert the indices of the elements in the `Vec<MyType>`, and provide a comparator object with a pointer/reference to the vector, so I could get the elements from the indices and compare them however I like.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34037318/578749), I can't do that with Rust's `BTreeSet`, and I must implement trait `Ord`. But I can't implement `Ord` unless I also store a reference to `Vec<MyType>` in every element of the `BTreeSet`. I don't want to copy the elements because they are big and complex objects.

I also tried using `Vec<Box<MyType>>` and `BTreeSet<&MyType>`, but then I found that I can't have both inside the same struct, as a struct can't store a reference using its own lifetime.

So, is there a Rust idiomatic and safe way of doing this (preferably without using `Rc<>`, as I know my elements are never removed)?

```rust
struct MyType {
    /// Ordered by insertion order.
    basis: Vec<Box /* ?? maybe ?? */<MyType>>;

    /// Alternative ordering for basis.
    alt1_ordering: BTreeSet</*???*/>;

    /// Other alternative ordering for basis.
    alt2_orderign: BTreeSet</*???*/>;
}
```

Comment: This is similar to [How to define an ordered Map/Set with a runtime-defined comparator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65533995/how-to-define-an-ordered-map-set-with-a-runtime-defined-comparator). I don't think you can do that, unfortunately.

Comment: Does it need to remain sorted on each insertion, or can you populate the the `Vec` and then produce sorted indices later?

Comment: @harmic It has to stay sorted with each insertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, is there a Rust idiomatic and safe way of doing this

Yes!

> preferably without using `Rc<>`

Oh.... well, no.  But the overhead of `Rc` should be negligible, and it makes the implementation super straightforward.  You already need a smart pointer type since the structure is recursive, anyway.

```
// Newtypes for implementing your alt1 and alt2 ordering.
struct Alt1Ordering(Rc<MyType>);
impl PartialEq for Alt1Ordering { ... }
impl PartialOrd for Alt1Ordering { ... }
impl Eq for Alt1Ordering {}
impl Ord for Alt1Ordering { ... }

struct Alt2Ordering(Rc<MyType>);
impl PartialEq for Alt2Ordering { ... }
impl PartialOrd for Alt2Ordering { ... }
impl Eq for Alt2Ordering {}
impl Ord for Alt2Ordering { ... }

struct MyType {
    /// Ordered by insertion order.
    basis: Vec<Rc<MyType>>,

    /// Alternative ordering for basis.
    alt1_ordering: BTreeSet<Alt1Ordering>,

    /// Other alternative ordering for basis.
    alt2_ordering: BTreeSet<Alt2Ordering>,
}

impl MyType {
    pub fn push(&mut self, value: MyType) {
        let value = Rc::new(value);
        
        self.basis.push(value.clone());
        self.alt1_ordering.insert(Alt1Ordering(value.clone()));
        self.alt2_ordering.insert(Alt2Ordering(value));
    }

    // Whatever accessors you need, e.g.:
    pub fn iter_basis(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item=&MyType> {
        self.basis.iter().map(|v| &**v)
    }
    
    pub fn iter_alt1(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item=&MyType> {
        self.alt1_ordering.iter().map(|v| &*v.0)
    }
    
    pub fn iter_alt2(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item=&MyType> {
        self.alt2_ordering.iter().map(|v| &*v.0)
    }
}
```

Note that `MyType` will not be `Send` nor `Sync` because it contains `Rc`.  However, as long as all of the methods that `clone` or destroy an `Rc` take `&mut self` then it should be safe to implement `Send` and `Sync`, because if you have a `&mut MyType` then no other references should exist.

Note that code you didn't write can make the `Send` and `Sync` implementations unsound. For example, if you `#[derive(Clone)]`, the compiler-generated implementation would make the trait implementations unsound since it would clone an `Rc` using a shared reference.

Alternatively, you can replace `Rc` with `Arc` to safely get `Send` and `Sync` without having to think about where you might clone/destroy `Rc`s.

---

It is theoretically possible to do this without `Rc` using pinning, but that requires `unsafe`, and I'd only investigate that route if the overhead of `Rc` proves to be significant (which I doubt will be the case).